# Prestashop faceted search customized value repeated per products how to

Tags: prestashop-1.7, faceted-search

After upgrade Prestashop & faceted module Prestashop faceted search customized value repeated per products how to resolve I am trying lots from back office uninstall & reinstall module but same issue
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUCcL.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otda0.png)

Comment: First, check if it is duplicated in the database? then update your post

Comment: Ok, let me check please